# Large Increase in Naive Bayes Accuracy results in decrease precision?

Tags: probability, naive-bayes, logarithm, accuracy

I am trying to classify (37 possible classes) a dataset that has 9 features and 900,000 occurrences. I have tried a couple different algorithms but the one that gave the lowest logarithmic loss was the naive bayes with 5.4.

The accuracy of this same naive bayes was 7% so I knew there was room for improvement.

After adding a new feature and that went through 2 different feature selection (chi2, and elasticnet) I was able to get the accuracy up to 23% but log loss score increased to 6.2?

How was such a large increase in accuracy accompanies by a decrease in the models precision?

Comment: Do you actually mean that the model was accurate only 7% of the time and then improved to being accurate only 23% of the time? Is this a binary or multiclass problem?

Comment: @Chaconne yes that is what I mean and it is a multiclass problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two metrics measure slightly different things.

Naive Bayes tries to learn how to approximate $P(\textrm{class } | \textrm{ data})$ from your training data. To classify new data, the algorithm takes each example and computes $P(\textrm{class}=c\ | \textrm{ data})$ for each possible class $c$. We label each test example with the $c$ that maximizes that probability.

The **accuracy** metric only concerns itself with final classification output. For each example in the test set, you get a 1 if the largest $c$ is the correct class, and a zero otherwise. Average these values together and you'll get an accuracy measurement. In other words, accuracy is 0/1 loss, scaled into a percentage.  **Log-loss**, however, considers the probability $P(\textrm{class}=c\ | \textrm{ data})$ directly. It's essentially the sum of the negative log-likelihoods of the *true* classes given your model. Kaggle defines it [slightly differently](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/MultiClassLogLoss), but in either case, the actual probabilities matter, not just which class's probability is the largest.

Here's an example. Suppose your first model is stupid but noncommittal. For 9 examples, it estimates  $P(\textrm{true class})=0.45$ and $P(\textrm{other}) =0.55$, while it does the opposite for one example.  This yields an accuracy of 10% and a log-loss of $\frac{1}{10}\big(9\log(0.45) + 1\log(0.55)\big) = 0.78$.

The second model is better but also more decisive, even when it's wrong. Suppose it calculates $P(\textrm{true class})=0.9$ for two examples, and $P(\textrm{true class})=0.1$ for the remaining eight. This classifier has an accuracy of 20%, but a log-loss of 1.8, which mimics your situation exactly.